# Autocomplete text not coming on top while selecting the data

Tags: json, react-native, npm, autocompletetextview

I'm new to react native I'm working on *AutoCompleteTextView* . I have one json file I need to display the country name in autocomplete view . I have display the country names of all countries. But while selecting the country it's not selecting. The json file which i'm displaying  [is](https://gist.github.com/erdem/8c7d26765831d0f9a8c62f02782ae00d).

My code for autocomplete is.

```
  render() {
    const { query } = this.state;

    return (
      <KeyboardAwareScrollView
    innerRef={ref => this.scrollView = ref} //... Access the ref for any other functions here
    contentContainerStyle={{flex: 1}}>
        <View>
          <View style={styles.autocompleteContainer}>
          <Autocomplete
    data={timezones}
    defaultValue={query}
    autoCapitalize="none"
    autoCorrect={false}
    onChangeText={text => this.setState({ query: text })}
    placeholder="Enter Country"

    renderItem={({ name, latlng }) => {

        const prodNames = latlng.map(item => item.prodNames);
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.setState({ query: text })}>
         <Text>{name} {prodNames}</Text >

        </TouchableOpacity>
        }}

    />  
          </View>
          <View>
            <Text>Some content</Text>
          </View>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting an error?

Try replacing this:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.setState({ query: text })}>
```

By this:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.setState({ query: name+''+prodNames })}>
```